# Высота дочернего элемента jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!

Столкнулась с проблемой:
У меня есть блок с кнопкой, по нажатию на который - блок с кнопкой пропадает и запускается видео.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть непосредственно блок с видео, у которого есть атрибут poster:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Постер представляет собой изображение с определенной высотой. Высоту блока с кнопкой я реализовала через абсолютное позиционирование. Т.е. получается, что до момента запуска видео, у меня высота блока с кнопкой = высоте постера.

Возникает проблема, когда я нажимаю на кнопку. Получается, что постер пропадает и начинает подгружаться видео, из-за чего происходит прыжок. А мне нужно от этого прыжка избавиться, сразу задать высоту, которая = высоте видео. Мне нужно от этого прыжка избавиться. Пробовала стилями, не получается.

var blockHeight = $('video').height();

$('.button-block').css('height',blockHeight);

HTML:

```
<video id='homepage-video' preload="metadata" poster="http://www.designstickers.com.ua/images/png/cv-22.jpg" data-video-id=""></video>


<div id="main-poster" data-mp4="">
  <div id='button' class="height-video">
    <button class="text-uppercase">Press
    </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.main-poster {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Можете выложить полный код?

Comment: Ну не ясновидящие же тут сидят...  Покажи код...

Comment: Обновила запись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так

```js
var video = $('.video');
var blockHeight = video.height();
var blockWidth = video.width();

var block = $('.block');

$(block).css({
  'height': video.height(),
  'width': video.width()
});

$('.button-block').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('hidden');
  video.removeClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.block {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.video {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <video id='homepage-video' class="video hidden" preload="metadata" poster="http://www.designstickers.com.ua/images/png/cv-22.jpg" data-video-id=""></video>
  <button class="button-block">Press</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Спасибо,это хорошо, но не плохо было бы принять  ответ...